# Loop in FutureBuilder doesnt work properly

Tags: flutter

I want to go through a loop in FutureBuilder. Everytime `snapshot.data.berichte[i].team == team`, I want to return the Card with its content. But only the first Card gets returned. So i++ does not get executed.

```
return FutureBuilder<BerichtList>(
        future: futureBerichte,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            for (var i = 0; i < snapshot.data.berichte.length; i++) {
              if (snapshot.data.berichte[i].team == team) {
                print(i);
                return Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: double.infinity,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  child: Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
                    elevation: 5,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
                          child: Text(
                            DateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm").format(
                                DateTime.parse(
                                    snapshot.data.berichte[i].spielDatum)),
                            style: TextStyles.body,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: Text(
                            snapshot.data.berichte[i].spiele,
                            style: TextStyles.body,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                          child: Text(
                            snapshot.data.berichte[i].ergebnis,
                            style: TextStyles.body,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                          /*   width: 350,
                              height: 800, */
                          child: Text(
                            snapshot.data.berichte[i].ueberschrift,
                            style: TextStyles.headline4,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30),

                          /*   width: 350,
                              height: 800, */
                          child: Text(
                            snapshot.data.berichte[i].bericht,
                            style: TextStyles.body,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              } else {}
            }
            return Container();
          } else
            return Center(child: AppProgressIndicator());
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

it is because you are returning the value directly from the FutureBuilder widget, and it completes the function, so the next index does not follow up! you should put your data in a parent widget like `Column` or `ListView` and then return it. for example:

```
return ListView(
   children: snapshot.data.berichte.map(item=>{
      if(item.team==team){
         return YOUR WIDGET
      }
     }).toList();
);
```